# How i make my button "go to top" work, he dosn't work

Tags: javascript

I write the code but when i click on the button he don't go up to the header as he have to do

```
(function() {
    'use-strict'

    function checkScroll() {
        let scrolled = window.pageYOffset;
        let coords = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

        if (scrolled > coords) {
            goTopBtn.classList.add('up_show');
        }
        if (scrolled < coords) {
            goTopBtn.classList.remove('up_show');
        }
    }

    function downToUp() {
        if (window.pageXOffset > 0) {
            window.scrollBy(0, -80);
            setTimeout(downToUp, 0);
        }
    }

    let goTopBtn = document.querySelector(".down_to_up");

    window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll);
    goTopBtn.addEventListener('click', downToUp);
})();
```

idk what i have to do

Comment: `if (window.pageXOffset > 0) {` isn't it `pageYOffset`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote you a short summary of how I program To-Top buttons most of the time. I didn't quite understand the CheckScroll function. Should the to top button only be shown when the user has scrolled down a specific amount of pixels?

If yes I can add to my answer.

**HTML-Code:**

```
<button id="scroll-to-top-button">
    Scroll to top
</button>
```

**Variant 1 - scroll to top of page:**

```
// select the button
const scrollToTopButton = document.getElementById('scroll-to-top-button');

// listen for clicks on the button
scrollToTopButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    window.scrollTo({
        top: 0, // specifies Y position
        behavior: 'smooth', // creates a smooth scroll effect
    });
});
```

**Variant 2 - scroll to specific element:**

```
// listen for clicks on the button
const scrollToTopButton = document.getElementById('scroll-to-top-button');

// listen for the click event
scrollToTopButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // select header element
    const header = document.querySelector('header');

    // scroll to the header element
    header.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth', // creates a smooth scroll effect
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the use strict, it is written with a space, not a hyphen!

You need to refer to the comment:

> isn't it pageYOffset?

Blessings

Comment: While this remark is correct, it does not address the question, and should have been made as a comment,